# Showing that a map $\mathrm{GL}(2,k) \to \mathrm{Gal}(k(x)/k)$ is a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory, group-homomorphism

This is Problem 15 from section 2 on page 26 of Patrick Morandi's *Field and Galois Theory*.

> Let $k$ be a field and $k(x)$ be the rational function field in one variable over $k$. Show that the map from the set of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices over $k$ to $\mathrm{Gal}(k(x)/k)$ given by
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> a & b \\
> c & d
> \end{pmatrix}
> \mapsto \varphi,
> $$
>   where $\varphi(x) = (ax+b)/(cx+d)$, is a group homomorphism.

However, my calculation shows that it must be an anti-homomorphism. I have given my work below.

I have already shown that every element $\varphi \in \mathrm{Gal}(k(x)/k)$ satisfies $\varphi(x) = (ax+b)/(cx+d)$ where
$$
\det \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \neq 0.
$$
So,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto \varphi,
$$
where $\varphi(x) = (ax+b)/(cx+d)$, is a well-defined function from $\mathrm{GL}(2,k)$ to $\mathrm{Gal}(k(x)/k)$. To show that it is a group homomorphism, I need to show that if
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \varphi \quad \text{and} \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
p & q \\
r & s
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \psi,
$$
then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
p & q \\
r & s
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
ap + br & aq + bs \\
cp + dr & cq + ds
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \varphi \circ \psi.
$$
However, my computation shows me that
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi \circ \psi (x) &= \varphi \left( \frac{px+q}{rx+s} \right)\\
&= \frac{p\left(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\right)+q}{r\left(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\right)+s}\\
&= \frac{(pa+qc)x+(pb+qd)}{(ra+sc)x+(rb+sd)}
\end{align},
$$
which is the image of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
p & q \\
r & s
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Thus, the given map is actually an anti-homomorphism from $\mathrm{GL}(2,k)$ to $\mathrm{Gal}(k(x)/k)$.

Could someone verify my calculation and/or confirm whether this is a typo in the textbook? It isn't mentioned as such in the [list of typos](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/Errata.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map as defined in the question details is an anti-homormorphism and not a homomorphism. Therefore, the problem is not stated correctly in the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a typo and your book is correct. This problem is "one of those things" and I think many people will relate to the confusion...

$\varphi \circ \psi$ is meant to be $$\varphi \circ \psi(x) = \frac{a \psi(x) + b}{c \psi(x) + d}.$$

Comment: @Brahadeesh After looking again I think it is just the step between $\varphi\left(\frac{px+q}{rx+s}\right) = \frac{p(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}) + q}{r(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}) + s}$ that doesn't make sense. Otherwise your approach is fine.

Comment: Just expand out $\varphi((px+q) / (rx+s))$. Without trying to use any tricks. I think this is the problem.